# Reading file with delimiter using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data in a file I dont know if it is delimited by space or tab

**Data In:**

```
id              Name                                                                                year    Age Score 

123456          ALEX BROWNNIS VND                                                                        0      19     115
123457          MARIA BROWNNIS VND                                                                       0      57     170
123458          jORDAN BROWNNIS VND                                                                      0      27     191
```

I read it the data with read_csv and using the tab delimited

```
df = pd.read_csv(data.txt,sep='\t')
```

**out:**

```
     id           Name                                                                                year  Age  Score 
0          123456  ALEX BROWNNIS VND                             ...                                     0   19     115
1          123457  MARIA BROWNNIS VND                            ...                                     0   57     170
2          123458  jORDAN BROWNNIS VND                           ...                                     0   27     191
```

There is a lot of a white spaces between the column. **Am I using delimiter correctly?** and when I try to process the column name, I got`key error` so I basically think the fault is use of `\t`.
What are the possible way to fix this problem?

Comment: I suppose the file you're reading is coming frm .CSV? Would you be able to read the CSV file directly to check what is used in delimiting the file?

Comment: It is a .txt file

Comment: Are all spaces same? Or they are random?

Comment: No it's not the same

Comment: Does `delimiter=r"\s+"` solves your problem?

Comment: no, Not solved!

Comment: Try `names=[<list of columns names>]`?

Comment: To find out if it's a space or tab, you can simply remove the spacing by backward button. See if the space gets deleted by big gap (TAB), or small spacing by spacing (Space).

Comment: @TommyLeong we are not confused at `tab` or `spaces`. Because `\s+` works for both tabs and spaces.

Comment: Can you provide that `txt` file? So, that we can try on our own/reproduce output (error) [mre] and answer you! You may change content but don't change spaces. Because that is our main problem.

Comment: I generally use \s\s+ to indicate two spaces or more.  `pd.read_csv(data.txt,sep='\s\s+')`  Another alternate is to use `read_fwf`

Comment: @Xitiz how can i add file to my post?

Comment: @ScottBoston I don't think we should do that, cuz `\s` mean single space and `\s+` mean upto last space. There can be many spaces. So, I don't think we should do `\s\s+`

Comment: @Prestige you should post from external sources. Cuz SO doesn't support file upload. How about `pastebin`. I haven't personally used it but I think there we can do paste and share link

Comment: '\s\s+' This means 2 or more spaces will be a separation. A single space is part of a string. I use this regex all the time.

Comment: Use `pd.read_fwf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem Solved:**

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep='\t',engine="python")
```

I added this line of code to remove space between columns and it's work

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two columns and the second one has variable number of words, you need to read it as a regular file and then combine second to last words.

```
id = [] 
Name = [] 
year = []
Age = []
Score = []
with open('data.txt') as f: 
    text = f.read() 
lines = text.split('\n') 
for line in lines: 
    if len(line) < 3: continue 
    words = line.split() 
    id.append(words[0]) 
    Name.append(' '.join(words[1:-3])) 
    year.append(words[-3])
    Age.append(words[-2])
    Score.append(words[-1])
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'id': id, 'Name': Name,
              'year': year, 'Age': Age, 'Score': Score})
```

Edit: you'd posted the overall data, so I'll change my answer to fit it.

Comment: Yes i tried this method too, but i got this error in multiples rows eg: `pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 7 fields in line 10, saw 10`

Comment: Try `engine="python"`.

Comment: Then maybe `\t+`?

Comment: @MichaelO. I don't think so, cuz `\t` strictly mean tab and there may not be exactly tab spaces. While `\s` mean single spaces and `\s+` mean multiple spaces. In answer that is clearly described!

Comment: No it's not working. Actually `\t+` don't show an error but i still got the same problem

Comment: @MichaelO. OP don't have only two columns. There is a large space which is random, so we aren't aware of how much spaces is there. Spaces is random. And doing your trick will be very lengthy for more then 2/3 column ***I think***

Comment: @Xitiz `split` without parameters groups the spaces together, so it does not matter how many of them are there.

Comment: Oh! Yeah! But creating new variable for a column is a bit lengthy, can we automate that too? I don't have exactly about in my mind but if you have you may post it. Because solving problem with changing data should also work and we have to make as easy as possible it is for future use also

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `skipinitialspace` parameter like in the following example.

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep='\t', delimiter=',', encoding="utf-8", skipinitialspace=True)
```

Pandas documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html